# Can I have variables extreme of integration?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, definite-integrals

Suppose you have a function $v(t)$ that you want to find. The condition is that it's integral is some fixed quantity. The integral is done between $0$ and $u(t)$, where $u(t)$ is an increasing function that tells us when we think we have to stop integrating. Now I would be tempted to write

$$\int_0^{u(t)} v(t) dt = C$$

where the $t$ inside the integral and on the extremes is actually the same.

Does this make sense? If not, what is a good formulation to find the function $v(t)$ I'm interested in?

Edit: Think of $v(t)$ as speed, $C$ the distance I want to travel and $u(t)$ the time I want to arrive there. The time I want to arrive changes, and when it does the velocity should change to ensure that the overall integral equals $C$.

Comment: What do you mean by "it's integral is some fixed quantity"?

Comment: @BrianFitzpatrick I'd like the integral of the function to be equal to $C$ for a fixed $C$.

Comment: By "integral" do you mean "antiderivative" or "definite integral"?

Comment: @BrianFitzpatrick Definite integral. You can interpret $v$ as a velocity, $C$ the distance I want to travel, and $u(t)$ as the time I want to arrive there

Comment: If $F$ is the antiderivative, then $F(u(t)) - F(0) = C$.

Comment: If you are worried about the $t$ in the integral, replace it with $u(a)$, then substitute $a=t$ at the end.

Comment: @CuddlyCuttlefish And what sense would that have? The point is that the time I want to arrive is different for every $t$, and that in turn changes my velocity in $t$ to match my new goal.

Comment: So you are changing the velocity function, not the time of arrival?

Comment: @CuddlyCuttlefish I am changing both.. As the time of arrival changes the velocity changes too to ensure that the integral still evaluates to $C$.

Comment: Formally, a limit of integration containing its own integration variable is meaningless. In physical terms: You can pick the duration of travel, and you can describe its position along that path as a function of time, but these are two different things (duration in time versus location in time.)

Comment: @Semiclassical Yes but if I wanted to find the solution to the problem I mentioned above? What would I do?